# WebClient DownloadFileAsync() work Incorect

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadfileasync

I use `WebClient` to download files from a server, but the downloaded file is not same (the file size is wrong):

Here's a screenshot (the downloaded file is on the right):

[image: Downloaded file]

And here's my code:

```
public void StartDownload(string fileToDownloadLink, string PathToSaveFile)         ///////// Try check file type..
    {
        try
        {
            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                //webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fileToDownloadLink), PathToSaveFile);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fileToDownloadLink);
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Worker.CancelAsync();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is causing the issue or not but I don't think that you should be using a `using` statement there. The point of a `using` block is disposing the object created when the block completes but you want to keep using that object until the file has been downloaded, so you should be disposing the `WebClient` inside `Client_DownloadFileCompleted` instead.

Comment: Also, are you sure that that encoding is correct?

Comment: This looks like an `EOL` problem (Notepad will display a line break for neither `CR` nor `LF`). Are you sure no changes are being made to the file on the server? Is your file on the left downloaded from the server (manually) **or is it the original file before uploading**?

Comment: It depends on the original encoding. Try `webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` ASCII encoding is improbable.

Comment: I check downloading file manually and file is OK. I will try download file without using() and write

Comment: I try other encoding options and still same result

Comment: I try other way I go to: http://piterrr70.nazwa.pl/www/app/content/Adam/Takie%20sobie.txt
and Save as and downloaded file is incorect like using WebClient :/ wtf..

Comment: @jmcilhinney I edit post. Look how I use WebClient, look ok ?!
I don't have no idea why I get wrong file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably find why this happened.. Server support only ASCII encoding look on file size after upload to server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B08We.png)

I forced the coding and it worked :) Now files are same :)